# How to simplify this code shared in image below?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to show div content on button click .and thee is 3 different button following 3 different content. I tried this logic and it made my code lengthy. how to simplify is code using loop or condition?

```js
 function replace1(){
            document.getElementById("con1").style.visibility="visible";
           
            document.getElementById("con2").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con3").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con4").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con5").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con6").style.visibility="hidden";
           
        }
        function replace2(){
            document.getElementById("con1").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con2").style.visibility="visible";
           
            document.getElementById("con3").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con4").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con5").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con6").style.visibility="hidden";
           
        }
        function replace3(){
            document.getElementById("con1").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con2").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con3").style.visibility="visible";
           
            document.getElementById("con4").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con5").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("con6").style.visibility="hidden";
           
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gohwd.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please share the HTML you are trying to manipulate as well.

Comment: You can also use common class names that needs to be modified. And then use either document.getElementsByClassName() or document.querySelectorAll() and iterate over them. But in case you don't want to touch the HTML, you can use a loop running from 1 to 6. I find modifying class names much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.active-button {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="replace-button" onclick="replace(1, this)"></button>
<button class="replace-button" onclick="replace(2, this)"></button>
<button class="replace-button" onclick="replace(3, this)"></button>
```

```js
function replace(visibleIndex, _this) {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.replace-button');
    buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove("active-button"));
    _this.classList.add("active-button");

    for(let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        let element = document.getElementById("con" + i)
        i === visibleIndex ? element.style.visibility = "visible" : element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will have to be updated every time an element is added or removed

Comment: what if want to change to color of button also as per the button content shown

Comment: @anu use class see modifed answer

Comment: it's not working.the color is not changing.

Comment: it's not working for me can you please help...the color of the button is not coming to normal when I click another button.

Comment: thanks a lot now its working properly.

Comment: I do not recommend inline event handlers. Also you should cache the buttons so the script does not have to get them each time it is exectued

Answer (score 1):

Use a class - add class="con" to each element - also use hidden instead of visibility since the hidden divs still will take up space

```
const toggle = id => cons
  .forEach(con => con.hidden = con.id !== id);
```

Here is a version that will change the colour of the button too.

You will need to use hidden or display:none to have the divs stay in one place

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const cons = document.querySelectorAll('.con');
  const buts = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

  const toggle = id => cons
    .forEach(con => con.hidden = con.id !== id);

  document.getElementById('nav').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('button');
    if (tgt.classList.contains('toggle')) {
      toggle(tgt.dataset.id)
      buts.forEach(but => but.classList.remove('active'));
      tgt.classList.add('active');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <button type="button" class="toggle" data-id="con1">Con 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="toggle" data-id="con2">Con 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="toggle" data-id="con3">Con 3</button>
</nav>
<div id="con1" class="con" hidden>
  <h1>Con 1</h1>
</div>
<div id="con2" class="con"hidden>
  <h1>Con 2</h1>
</div>
<div id="con3" class="con" hidden>
  <h1>Con 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you get `.con` from? OP's post doesn't mention such a classname.

Comment: Also, `.hidden` isn't the same as `.style.visibility`, which might have implications for whatever OP is doing, right?

Comment: .con is id of content div

Comment: .con is the CLASS of each content div. If you have another class that is common to all divs, use that instead

Comment: the div is positioned at the same place. and as the button is clicked the button name color should be changed and the div content also.

Comment: @anu see update

Comment: in my code button already have an id....and if I give data-id to the button  ....i think the code is not working because of this...!

Comment: ID and data-id are not related

Comment: But you can of course help me if you post what your code DOES look like. Note I wrapped the buttons in a nav